# Formal definition of function composition.

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

This is something that is bothering me for a while now.

Suppose we have two functions

$$f: A \to B$$
$$g: B \to C$$

Then the composition is defined by $g\circ f : A \to C: a \mapsto g(f(a))$
and one can write this in a nice commutative diagram.

However, all we actually need is that $f(A) \subseteq B$, so we can define function composition for functions

$$f: A\to B$$
$$g: C \to D$$

where $f(A) \subseteq C$.

The problem is then that we don't really get commutative diagrams, but rather must restrict one of the functions domains/codomains to make things work, or compose with an inclusion map or something like that.

Which definition is preferred?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the 6 AM talking, but I don't see how you get a commutative diagram here.

Comment: If you have a map $A \to B$ and a map $B \to C$, the composition $A \to C$ gives you an obvious map making the triangular diagram between $A,B,C$ commute.

Comment: Yes, I see that I can do that. But the question is more like: is the second definition standard, or is it some abuse of notation?

Comment: Oh yep I see what you're doing now. It's a bit early yet. :P In the case where the domain doesn't match the range, what you could do is add one more step with a canonical inclusion ($i(f(a)) = f(a)$). $f:A\to \operatorname{ran}(f) $, $i:\operatorname{ran}(f) \to B$, then you have arrows from $A\to\operatorname{ran}(f)$ and $\operatorname{ran}(f)\to B$. After that you get a nice diagram when you tie $g$ in. I think this is a bit overkill and no one would argue against using the original diagram in this setting.

Comment: You could also restrict $g$ to be defined on $\operatorname{ran}(f)$, but you would lose information by doing so and that's far from ideal. The only reason to do what is in my previous comment is if you want the diagram to make it explicit that there's a mismatch in domain and range.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Why would one loose information? Wouldn't it be a more general definition if we define $g \circ f$ for $f: A \longrightarrow B$ and $g: f(A) \longrightarrow C$?

Comment: @Jan it's a much easier diagram BUT you lose all information about $g$ that lives outside of $\operatorname{ran}(f)$. For the purposes of this diagram, it doesn't matter, but as a personal preference it seems pretty non-ideal. Also you have to do the restriction outside of the diagram which is kind of funky, too. You could do a restriction but it would cease to be a commutative diagram at that point.

Comment: Since it might be difficult to determine the range of a function, one should define the composition of $f$ and $g$ on the domain $f^{-1}\bigl(\mathrm{ran}(f)\cap\mathrm{dom}(g)\bigr)$.